# Magento2: Importing additional images programatically - PHP error

Tags: php, import, magento2.4

I am trying to set up a script to import additional images for products programatically, from the var/import/images folder. I am running it on the command line, via PuTTY. The following code works and shows me the product name but once I uncomment the 2 lines starting with $product it fails without showing any error. Error log says

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING) in /home/owlbarnradesyste/public_html/testcustomer.php on line 28 which is the $product > save(); line.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
     
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require 'app/bootstrap.php';
     
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
     
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
     
    try {
            
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(17);
        echo $product->getName();
       
        //$product->addImageToMediaGallery('var/import/images/111217.jpg', array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
        //$product->save();
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }   
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$product->addImageToMediaGallery` syntax looks correct. You should use full path to image file /var/www/magento2/var/import/blah'

`$product->save()` is deprecated

Try using the save method of ProductRepositoryInterface (Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface)

```
$this->_productRepository->save($product);
```

Comment: Thanks - but it's still not working. I'm not sure i'm using the ProductRepositoryInterface correctly. I have added in `use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;` and then `$productRepository = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);` further down, and changed the save to `$productRepository->save($product);` I also tried it your way but didn't work either. I have tried the full path and also `$product->addImageToMediaGallery(__DIR__ .'/var/import/images/111217.jpg'` and every combination of different paths and productrepository. Am I missing something?

Comment: Changed it to `$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$productRepository = $objectManager->get(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);` Progress, a new error "Path "/home/sitename/public_html/var/import/images/111217.jpg" cannot be used with directory "/home/sitename/public_html/pub/media/"

Answer (score 1):

Final code looks like this now, thanks! Still getting the other error though, but I will mark your answer as correct and post another question. Think it's permissions.

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product; 
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); 
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$productRepository = $objectManager->get(ProductRepositoryInterface::class);

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$websiteId = $storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId(); 
 
try {
        
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(17);
    $product->setStoreId($storeId);
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery(__DIR__ .'/var/import/images/111217.jpg', array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
    $productRepository->save($product);
    //$this->_productRepository->save($product);
echo "saved";
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```